# R data frame select by global variable

Tags: r, global-variables, dataframe

I'm not sure how to do this without getting an error.  Here is a simplified example of my problem.

Say I have this data frame DF

```
a   b  c  d
1   2  3  4
2   3  4  5
3   4  5  6
```

Then I have a variable

```
x <- min(c(1,2,3))
```

Now I want do do the following

```
y <- DF[a == x]
```

But when I try to refer to some variable like "x" I get an error because R is looking for a column "x" in my data frame. I get the "undefined columns selected" error

How can I do what I am trying to do in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
> x <- min(DF$a)
> DF[DF$a == x,]
  a b c d
1 1 2 3 4
```

An easier way (avoiding the 'x' variable) would be this:

```
> DF[which.min(DF$a),]
  a b c d
1 1 2 3 4
```

or this:

```
> subset(DF, a==min(a))
  a b c d
1 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: The "x" was an example because I'm comparing to some other data.  First part you listed is the syntax I didn't know about but needed

Answer (score 4):

You may benefit from reading an *Introduction to R*, especially on matrices, data.frames and indexing.  Your `a` is a column of a data.frame, your `x` is a scalar. The comparison you have there does not work.

Maybe you meant

```
R> DF$a == min(c(1,2,3))
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
R> DF[,"a"] == min(c(1,2,3))
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
R>
```

which tells you that the first row fits but not the other too. Wrapping this in `which()` gives you indices instead.